# Show text while copy() function is copying file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm copying a zip folder from remote server to wordpress theme folder, but while copying screen becomes blank, I want to show some text like: "Copying" or "Updating".

Code I'm using:

```
copy($packageurl, get_theme_root() . "/vegetapronew.zip");
```

Comment: you'll see some CSS/JS/jQueryAjax for that.

Comment: You will need to look into the [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) functions and try them out.